# adminer container keep recreating itself and auto start

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I have a container from (https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mysql/) in (docker toolbox) started with with this yml using command , will k

"docker-compose -f stack.yml up"

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql-test
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
```

even i delete the container, it will recreate (mysql_adminer.1.4cxxxxxxxxxxxxx5iyt) it and start it, everyone how to stop that?

what solutions i have taken:
1. command: docker update --restart=no containerId => not work 
2. changed in .yml restart: "no" => not work 
3. docker-compose -f stack.yml down => output:Removing network mysqltest_default, no effect 
4. restart virtual-box image => it stills start when the docker start
5. delete every thing but it stills exist 
 https://s31.postimg.cc/5feduonfv/adminer.jpg

how can i remove that container except format the drive?

solutions:
$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
orbx4v7ipg7s        mysql_adminer       replicated          1/1                 adminer:latest      *:8080->8080/tcp
wm515zc39ltf        mysql_db            replicated          0/1                 mysql-test:latest

$ docker service rm mysql_adminer
mysql_adminer

$ docker service rm mysql_db
mysql_db

Comment: remove this restart: always from yml file.

Comment: do you have mysql-test image?

Comment: the mysql-test image was renamed

Comment: why you use image mysql-test instead of mysql?

Comment: i just want to delete that......

Answer (score 1):

Remove `restart: always` OR change always to no from docker-compose yml file.

**restart**

`no` is the default restart policy, and it does not restart a container under any circumstance. When `always` is specified, the container always restarts. The `on-failure` policy restarts a container if the exit code indicates an on-failure error.

```
restart: "no"

restart: always

restart: on-failure

restart: unless-stopped
```

Ref. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: tried, it stills recreating and start a new container

Comment: have you run docker-compose down and docker-compose up again?